# NullreferenceException when opening SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, nullreferenceexception, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

After running the Configuration Wizard in SharePoint 2010 (had to do this because of permission issues) I cannot open any Document Library like "Pages". I receive the following Error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties() +134
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs() +44
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext) +329
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalAvailable() +44
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls() +60
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable() +15
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427
```

A "normal" List can be opened without any problem. I alreade deactivated and re-activated "SharePoint Server Publishing" and "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It maybe has something to do with the User Profile Service Application.

look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475253/Object-null-reference-error-when-opening-the-Site

According to this article, deleting the user profile service application fixes the error.